# Kinect power - Create shutdown issue

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having some issues where my create is powering down after the kinect is on for a few minutes. I am worried it has something to do with my circuit I made http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20Kinect%20to%20an%20iRobot%20Create. I could have something done incorrectly on the circuit. * The setup I currently have is what that tutorial shows. Coming off the create power outputs. *

I was wondering, since I am using a full ATX power supply can I just take a 12volt line and use that for powering my kinect? Is there any drawbacks issues. *My power supply is a DC power supply for car PCs. *

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10746/kinect-power---create-shutdown-issue/) by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Experiments showed me the following:

Kinect can actually handle a small voltage swing pretty well. I had no problems with 11 to 13.5V although I would advice against it. Using a typical 7812 or LM1084-12 is the best option. Also a ATX output provides a stable 12V (sometimes they do need a minimal load).
The kinect PSU is rated for 1 or 1.5A, but using the Kinect with camera + pointcloud only, I never got it above 500mA.
However the current peaks can bring the robot down. (both lowering the battery voltage and draining the battery faster)
This was not tested on an Create but on a Roomba.
This is why we choose to sell our Turtlebots with a battery connection.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-26**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.